# How do I compare a cell value with a range of values on 2 dirrerent sheets and return a Text I specify

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

In Excel I have 3 sheets in the same workbook.

- I want to compare column A on "Sheet 1" with Column B on "Sheet 2" and Column b on "Sheet 3".
- If I find an exact match on anywhere in column B "Sheet 2" I want cell B next to the compared value on "Sheet 1" column A to say "Sheet 2"
- If I find an exact match on anywhere in column B "Sheet 3 I want cell B next to the compared value on "Sheet 1" column A to say "Sheet 3"

The following formula works perfectly to compare only sheet 2 but I cannot figure out how to modify it to work and compare values on both sheet 2 and sheet 3.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,'Sheet 2'!$b$2:$b$30,FALSE)),"","Sheet 2")
```

Please see the images below.

Current results:

[image]

End results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in place of `""` put another formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,'Sheet 2'!$b$2:$b$30,FALSE)),IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,'Sheet 3'!$b$2:$b$30,FALSE)),"","Sheet 3"),"Sheet 2")
```

So when no match is found on sheet 2 it will look at sheet 3.  If a match is found on sheet 3 then it will return "sheet 3".  If not it will return the blank cell.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Answer (score 0):

use name manager and give a name to

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,'Sheet 2'!$b$2:$b$30,FALSE)),"","Sheet 2")
```

as SHT_2
and then give a name to

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,'Sheet 3'!$b$2:$b$30,FALSE)),"","Sheet 3")
```

as SHT_3

then a final formula of

```
if(SHT_2="",SHT_3,SHT_2)
```

as SHT

then in you B column just enter the `=SHT` formula